# LVM volume group is not activated at startup

Tags: linux, systemd, xen, lvm2

I have installed XCP-ng on a physical server. I used a 500 GB SSD and let XCP-ng use the whole disk, of which only 15 GiB is used by XCP-ng; the rest is free space in the VG.

Now, I created a new LV on that VG using all the free space. This LV I used as SR storage (local LVM) in XCP-ng and it works as expected.

The issue is that is somehow creates a ‘nested’ VG, at least the LV created by me seems to behave like a VG. However, it is not automatically activated at startup.

When the system boots, the ‘main’ VG is automatically activated, with all LVs on it (including the one I have created), but run `vgchange -ay`, it activates a new VG (with the size of the LV created by me). Only then I can use that storage in XCP-ng and VMs.

Any idea how can I make it auto-activate these ‘nested’ VGs?

I have tried to:

- create a `systemd` service to run `vgchange -ay`, but it fails with exit code `3`;
- modify `/etc/lvm/lvm.config` to include `auto_activation_volume_list` set to an array of names of both VGs.

Nothing helped so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by putting the required commands into `crontab`.

Note that one could put the commands into a script or even log the output. Also I appended a command (`xe pbd-plug`) to *attempt to plug in the PBD to the host*. That way I could access the VMs’ HDDs.

```bsh
# cat /var/spool/cron/root
@reboot /usr/sbin/vgchange -ay &> /dev/null; /usr/sbin/vgchange -ay &> /dev/null; /opt/xensource/bin/xe pbd-plug uuid=71389ed2-d0e3-ba07-d734-b907757d9c44 &> /dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a systemd unit and arrange it to start before XCP components:

```bsh
# Make sure the file doesn't already exist
$ ls /etc/systemd/system/lvm-activate.service
ls: cannot access /etc/systemd/system/lvm-activate.service

# create it
$ echo >/etc/systemd/system/lvm-activate.service <<END
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Before=xenopsd-xc.service
RequiredBy=xenopsd-xc.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/vgchange -ay
END

# enable it
$ systemctl daemon-reload
$ systemctl enable lvm-activate
```

Answer (score 0):

On RHEL8 (CentOS8) you can add the VG activation to /etc/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/lvm2-monitor.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc. using dmeventd or progress polling
Documentation=man:dmeventd(8) man:lvcreate(8) man:lvchange(8) man:vgchange(8)
Requires=dm-event.socket
After=dm-event.socket dm-event.service lvm2-activation.service
Before=local-fs-pre.target shutdown.target
DefaultDependencies=no
Conflicts=shutdown.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
Environment=LVM_SUPPRESS_LOCKING_FAILURE_MESSAGES=1
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/lvm vgchange -ay
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/lvm vgchange --monitor y
ExecStop=/usr/sbin/lvm vgchange --monitor n
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=sysinit.target
```